# Tabs component in footer

Tags: material-design-lite

Is it possible to put the tab links in the footer
and the rest of the tab content in the main section?
I have tried it, but once I put the tab links in the footer, the tab component stops working all together.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, tabs in the footer are not specified by Material Design. It wouldn't be supported as a default function, but could possibly be hacked and made to work. With that though, no guarantee on updates not breaking it.

If however they are specified, point it out please and we can take a look into either explaining better if it is supported or get the code fixed to work right.

Comment: the reason I want the tabs on the bottom is to have a like a navigation bar like jQuery Mobile has the ability to put a navbar in the footer. that way the tabs can switch the content, and each tab panel has its own card since MDL does not have a card overlay option like Materialize does

Comment: That doesn't follow Material Design's specification. Unless something changes within that to allow it then it would be very difficult for us to implement it. That is where you need to change site design or use the MDL layout component. You could write your own layout system then use other MDL components within that.

Comment: can I use MDL with jQuery Mobile layout structure ? will there be any conflicts?

Comment: I have no clue, give it a shot and see. I'm not sure what would break unless our resets conflict with each other.